# Is there a good way to search for EC2 instances running as on-demand via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Is there a good way to search for EC2 instances running as on-demand via CLI for a given region ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you run describe-instances command, if InstanceLifecycle property is not present, then it is an on-demand instance. The CLI command would look like:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,InstanceLifecycle]' --region us-east-2 --output text | grep -v spot
```

[This](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=804665) Amazon forum that has answer. Describe instances CLI reference can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html).

Comment: Hadn't found that forum when I wrote my answer. Removing my answer.